# Get multiple Tags

Tags: mysql, django, django-templates

I am designing a blog with each blog holding multiple tags.

I use `{% blog.get_tags.0 %}` to get the tag from the tag field in the mysql table.

What I want to do is filter by multiple tags, like this:`{% if blog.get_tags.0 == "Tag1" and blog.get_tags.1 == "Tag2"%}`

I've stored the tags as Tag1, Tag2 in the Tag field in the blog table. `{{blog.get_tags.1}}` displays Tag2 but does not work in `if` statement.

How do I use Tag2 in the conditional statement.

Comment: possibly want to try equality on the str field? `{% if blog.get_tags.0.name == "Tag1" and blog.get_tags.1.name == "Tag2"%}`. Also just pointing out that you're code shows an AND conditional, where Tag1 is in the list at index 0 and Tag2 is at index 1. If they were to be in the opposite order, the conditional would fail. You may be looking for something more like an `in` conditional: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator

Comment: @Ben using ``` in ``` worked for me with this format: ``` {% if "Tag2" in blog.get_tags.1%} ``` but  .name didn't. Thank you for your answer, much appreciated :)
However what if I do not know the index of the Tag2. How can I can i make something like ``` {% if "Tag2" in blog.get_tags%} ``` work?

Comment: if `blog.get_tags` returns a list, then `{% if "Tag2" in blog.get_tags%}` will work

Comment: @Ben `blog.get_tags` returns [u'Tag1', u' Tag2'] and `{% if "Tag1" in blog.get_tags%}` only works for Tag1 and not Tag2.